# How to save data and use it later?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I'm C# and Unity beginner and I am programming a Space-Shooter Game. I want to create a table which contains the enemy data `(EnemyID, EnemyHealth, EnemyType)`. Should I use Array, list, or dictionary? 

Example:

```
|EnemyID|EnemyHealth|EnemyType
|001    |50         |enemy1
|005    |100        |enemy2
...
```

But how to save this? It must be possible to add or remove Enemy and change its Health ... Do I need an Array, List or a dictionary?

Comment: Most compact way to use data in App is POCO object and List<T>. To persist data - Database, custom file, Dataset and xml-serialization. JSON serialization, etc

Comment: And what about a class called `enemy` with three properties! or save to a database and a table called `enemy` with three column.

Comment: @S.Akbari `Enemy` = POCO. Should be 6 lines of code including { }. YOu need persister that will save it. This is what entity framework essentially does - it does it all for you

Comment: look into SQLite implementation in the Unity3d

Comment: So if i want to change and add or remove enemys while the game, a database for example SQLite is the best?

Comment: It actually depends what you want to do with it. Use sql to save big data in storage/memory card etc, but use only dataset or you may create class like in Daniel's answer to operate on enemies during runtime

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enemyDatas = new List<EnemyData>
        {
            new EnemyData
            {
                EnemyName = "Name1",
                EnemyHealth = 50,
                EnemyId = 1,
                EnemyType = EnemyType.Bad
            },
            new EnemyData
            {
                EnemyName = "Name2",
                EnemyHealth = 100,
                EnemyId = 2,
                EnemyType = EnemyType.VeryBad
            }
        };
    }
}

public class EnemyData
{
    public int EnemyId { get; set; }
    public int EnemyHealth { get; set; }
    public EnemyType EnemyType { get; set; }
    public string EnemyName { get; set; }
}

public enum EnemyType
{
    Bad,
    VeryBad
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer, imo (and what I was in the process of typing.)  You should extend it even further with the List containing a Class called `Enemy` who has an `EnemyData` property on it, for that information.  Then you can even have a method in the `Enemy` class that grabs all of the data, at once, in the order you need it.

Comment: This is not suitable for Unity, you cannot use main.

Comment: This should give an advice.

Comment: Unity is editor oriented, you should set your class so it show in editor.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataTable for this.
e.g.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (string));
dt.Columns.Add("Health", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof (string));

DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["ID"] = "a1";
row["Health"] = 40;
row["Type"] = "type1";

dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: DataTable is from Data namespace which is not available in Unity.

Comment: Thank @fafase, I already wonder already

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Choosing_the_right_collection_type

Array if you need a defined collection and won't change it later. You have 5 players and there will not be 6 of them, use array.

For your enemies, I would guess you plan on adding and removing, use list.

Each of your enemies is a distinct one, that is for instance some type of bosses, use dictionary so that you can find a specific enemy without iterating.

If you wish to save those data, best is to use the JsonUtility and save a text file

```
[Serializable]
public class Root{
    public Enemy[] enemies;
    public Root(Enemy[] enemies){
       this.enemies = enemies;
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Enemy
{
   public int EnemyID; 
   public int EnemyHealth; 
   public EnemyType enemyType;
}
public enum EnemyType{ None, Soldiers, Boss }
```

then you save:

```
static void SaveEnemies(Enemies [] enemies, string path){
    Root root = new Root(enemies);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(root);
    File. WriteAllText(path, root);
}
```

Unity json serializer does not support collection as top object so you need to wrap it in a root object as I did.

Then you can retrieve next time:

```
Enemy[] GetEnemies(string path){
    string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
    Root root = JsonUtility<Root>(json);
    return root.enemies;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it whith a list.